# HTML 5 Websocket and Java_Websocket by TooAllNate

Tags: java, javascript, html, websocket

I got a big problem with using the HTML5 websocket in combination with  ["java_websocket" by TooAllNate](https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket).

I use the standard functions of HTML5 websocket, but especially the `onmessage()` function makes me cry. My current problem is, that i only get message from the server directly after load the page, that means, if the page is running, for example for 2 min, and isnt reloaded, i cant receive any new messages.

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8887"); 
ws.onmessage = function(evt)
{
alert(evt.data);
}
```

Is anyone there, who got the same Problem or can help me?

Best Regards

Comment: Used this library, but didn't get such problem. Do you get your ws connection disconnected after those 2 minutes? Does your Java code actually send new messages after those 2 minutes? You could check it with Wireshark for example

Comment: The problem is that the "onMessage"-function in TooAllNate ist only fire, if it gets a message from the html 5 websocket. But how can i see independent messages to the html websocket?